# vba userform checking the GroupName instead of an individual button

Tags: vba, userform, groupname

I'm using a VBA Userform.  The MassPrompt userform has a set of six GroupNames and some text boxes.  Each GroupName contains two or more radio buttons.
I'd like the following code to be triggered anytime any element within the GroupName "GROnly" changes.  If the user made an inappropriate button choice in "GROnly" based on the choice in another group, I'd like to display a warning message and present the MassPrompt userform again.
Right now, I've assigned the code to the one button "GROnly_yes".  It works, but only when that one button is clicked.  How do I position this within the UserForm code to trigger anytime a button with the GroupName "GROnly" is clicked?  Thanks for looking at this.

```
Private Sub GROnly_yes_Click()
'Prompt if the GROnly is true and it's inappropriate for the GSetting choice
  If GROnly_yes = True And GSetting_renewal = True _
  Then
    GROnly_yes = False
    GROnly_no = True
    MsgBox ("The GROnly can't be chosen with a Renewal." & vbNewLine & _
            "The GROnly button has been changed to 'NO'.")
    UserForm_Initialize
  End If
  'Other IF statements here.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, `GRonly` is the GroupBox that contains (let's say) the `radio_button_1` and `radio_button_2`.

The reason why the code doesn't trigger is that when he/she changes the value of one radio-button is not clicking on the GroupBox, but rather changing the value of that single radio-button.

You will have to add the code to the `_Change` event of the radio button objects. This is an example:

```
Sub myFunctionalCode()
    'your code here
End Sub

Private Sub radio_button_1_Change()
    myFunctionalCode
End Sub
Private Sub radio_button_2_Change()
    myFunctionalCode
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.  That would work.

In the meantime, I came up with another alternative as well.  I removed the code from:

```
Private Sub GROnly_yes_Click()
```

And I moved it to the button that the user clicks to submit the form:

```
Private Sub ContinueButton_Click()
```

In my original code I had to change `UserForm_Initialize` to `Exit Sub` to make the code work in the "submit" button.

Thanks again for your help.
Phil